# Access Azure EventHub with WebSocket and proxy

Tags: python, websocket, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to access Azure EvenHub but my network makes me use proxy and allows connection only over https (port 443)
Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubproducerclient?view=azure-python

I added proxy configuration and TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket parametr and my Producer looks like this:

```
async def run():
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
        "Endpoint=sb://my_eh.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=eh-sender;SharedAccessKey=MFGf5MX6Mdummykey=",
        eventhub_name="my_eh",
        auth_timeout=180,
        http_proxy=HTTP_PROXY,
        transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket,
    )
```

and I get an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/uamqp/authentication/cbs_auth_async.py", line 74, in create_authenticator_async
    raise errors.AMQPConnectionError(
uamqp.errors.AMQPConnectionError: Unable to open authentication session on connection b'EHProducer-a1cc5f12-96a1-4c29-ae54-70aafacd3097'.
Please confirm target hostname exists: b'my_eh.servicebus.windows.net'
```

I don't know what might be the issue.
Might it be related to this one ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-c/issues/50#issuecomment-501437753

Comment: Just adding a proxy may not be enough if that proxy is not configured to allow websockets. I had this problem before. Only notice after a change on proxy provider. 

Your network admin should be able to see if the websocket messages are passing through or if there is any configuration for websockets in place or not.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to set up a proxy that the SDK uses to access EventHub. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/proxy.py) that shows you how to set the HTTP_PROXY dictionary with the proxy information. Behind the scenes when proxy is passed in, it automatically goes over websockets.

As @BrunoLucasAzure suggested checking the ports on the proxy itself will be good to check, because based on the error message it looks like it made it past the proxy and cant resolve the endpoint.